# what is the meaning of __18CXX and __PCB__ in picc codes

Tags: pic, pic18, mplab-c18

I commonly see the following lines of compiler-related codes :

```
#if defined(__18CXX) ... #endif
```

and

```
#if (defined(__PCB__) || defined(__PCH__) || defined(__PCM__)) ... #endif
```

How can I know the meaning of each one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**18CXX** is a predefined macro to indicate the Microchip C18 compiler. See section 2.6 in the ‘MPLAB C18 C COMPILER USER’S GUIDE’. The others are CCS C compilers: PCB is for 12-bit opcodes, PCM is for 14-bit opcodes, and PCH is for 16-bit. See ‘CCS C Compiler Manual'.